# How to find a match of words in two strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, overlap

I have two strings like

`My name is Bogdan` and `Bogdan and I am from Russia`

I need to get word `Bogdan` from this strings. I always know what end of first sentence == start of second sentence.

How can I find this overlapping.

My solution returns similar chars

```
res = list(set('My name is Bogdan').intersection(set('Bogdan and i am from Russia')))
print(res)
```

Returns

```
['i', 'n', 'g', 'm', ' ', 's', 'B', 'a', 'd', 'o']
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with **Bogdan**?

Comment: Two strings can be without spaces and dots like `mynameisbogdan` and `bogdanand...`

Comment: Can the overlap be more than one word, or part of a word?

Comment: @BogdanMadzhuga You should add this additional requirement to the question, as a few answers rely on words being separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start by overlapping the two strings maximally and then iterate by reducing the overlap:

```
def find_overlap(s1, s2):
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        test1, test2 = s1[i:], s2[:len(s1) - i]
        if test1 == test2:
            return test1

s1, s2 = "My name is Bogdan", "Bogdan and I am from Russia"
find_overlap(s1, s2)
# 'Bogdan'
s1, s2 = "mynameisbogdan", "bogdanand"
find_overlap(s1, s2)
# 'bogdan'
```

As you can see this also works if the two strings do not contain spaces.

This has O(n) runtime, but could be reduced to O(min(n, m)) if you first determine which of the two strings is shorter.

If you expect the string to find to be much shorter than even the shortest of the two strings, you can make this even O(k), where k is the length of the string to find by starting with a minimal overlap:

```
def find_overlap(s1, s2):
    for i in range(1, len(s1) + 1):
        if i == len(s2):
            return None
        test1, test2 = s1[-i:], s2[:i]
        if test1 == test2:
            return test1
```

Comment: Yes i found simillar solutions right now. Thank you

Comment: You should mark his answer as correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Can use set intersection

```
l1="My name is Bogdan"
l2="Bogdan and I am from Russia"
print(set(l1.split())&set(l2.split())) # set('Bogdan')
```

List comprehension

```
l1="My name is Bogdan"
l2="Bogdan and I am from Russia"
[i for i in l1.split() if i in l2.split()] ['Bogdan']
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option, with for loop:

```
def shared_words(s1, s2):
  res = []
  l_s1, l_s2 = set(s1.split()), set(s2.split())
  for ss1 in l_s1:
    if ss1 in l_s2: res.append(ss1)
  return res
```

Apply to the string:

```
s1 = "My name is Bogdan"
s2 = "Bogdan and I am from Russia"
print(shared_words(s1, s2)) #=> ['Bogdan']
```

Or, using regex to split only words:

```
import re

def shared_words(s1, s2):
  res = []
  l_s1, l_s2 = set(re.findall(r'\w+',s1)), set(re.findall(r'\w+',s2))
  for ss1 in l_s1:
    if ss1 in l_s2: res.append(ss1)
  return res
```

To get:

```
s1 = "My name is Bogdan, I am here"
s2 = "Bogdan and I am from Russia."
print(shared_words(s1, s2)) #=> ['Bogdan', 'I', 'am']
```

Comment: The least you should do is compute the split of `s2` only once, instead of every loop iteration. I would also put it into a `set` to get constant time `in`.